# Make sure that the printer actually printed the PrintDocument

Tags: c#, winforms, printdocument

I am creating an application in C # that sends a string to the printer using the PrintDocument. However I need to make sure that the printer printed the string. In case of error I need to log this error. I tried using the Win32_Printer but the return codes are not consistent. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can try querying the print spooler using the Print Spooler API. Or you can use `System.Printing.PrintQueue` and `System.Printing.PrintJobInfo` and find your documents and query their status. I've done it both ways in the past but don't have the code handy with me at the moment. But hopefully it can get you started.

Comment: can you send me a exemple?

Comment: No, as i stated I don't have access to them at the moment. But Google how to use the PrintQueue and PrintJobInfo classes or search this site for them.

Comment: I get the PrintQueue and return this to my printer: 
ret = printQueue.IsInError || printQueue.IsOutOfMemory ||  printQueue.IsOutOfPaper || printQueue.IsPaperJammed || printQueue.IsNotAvailable || printQueue.IsOffline;